# Separating frontend and backend (as REST API)

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, express, restful-architecture

I am doing a side project, with purpose of learning to separate front-end and backend, and I decided to use express with node, to design a REST Api as my backend.

My question is, how do I authenticate my restful api. I saw some tutorials, but they always connect frontend and backend by using serverside rendering with jade or ejs, and I'm not interested with that.

How do I authenticate each user and give them access only to certain data and also how do I design endpoints that are only accessible by my front-end application?

I would really appreciate help. Also you can send links to articles that describe this king of authentication and project architecture, because I feel that i'm looking in the wrong places, and need some help.

Comment: You should have a look at https://jwt.io/

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what i was looking for!